# Form search with spring thymeleaf MVC?

Tags: mysql, forms, spring-mvc, search, thymeleaf

In my site I have a list of products extracted from a database, the results are aggregated into a simple list with select / option. Now I would like to change this with a multi-word search form with the word autocomplete.

This is my select/option list:

```js
$("#Product").change(function(){
 var webProductId = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-webProductId'); 
 var requestData = { webProductId: webProductId };
 yada.ajax([[@{/product/list}]], requestData, function(responseText, responseHtml) {
 $('div.sinVotoInner').replaceWith(responseHtml);
 yada.initHandlersOn(responseHtml);
});
```

```html
<select id="wsProduct">
  <option value="Products" id="Product" selected>Product</option>
  <option th:each="webProduct : ${webProducts}"
 th:attr="data-webProductId=${webProduct.id}"
 th:text="|${webProduct.name} ${webProduct.description}|">Product 1 Description 1</option>
   </select>
```

This is my home controller:

```js
@RequestMapping("/")
 public String home(Model model) {
  
  List<WebProduct> webProducts = webProductRepository.findByEnabledTrueOrderByNameAsc();
  model.addAttribute("webProducts", webProducts);

  return "/home";
 }
```

And this is my repository:

```js
List<WebLocation> findByEnabledTrueOrderByNameAsc();

 /**
  * @param productId
  * @return 
  */
 @Query(value="select * from WebProduct wp where wp.product_id = :productId", nativeQuery = true)
 WebProduct findByProductId(@Param("productId") long productId);
```

How do I change this code to include a working search form? Search must work for any word you've entered and search suggestions (such as google) appear in the search form.

Comment: search suggestions would be done using javascript + ajax calls to the backed. I don't see where thymeleaf would be used in this scenario? you just put a plain text box and listen to keyboard events, make async REST calls to the back-end to get the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```html
List<WebProduct> webProducts = webProductRepository.findByWord("%"+word+"%");
```

The query:

```html
@Query(value="select * from WebProduct wp where wp.name like :word or wp.description like :word", nativeQuery = true)
 List<WebProduct> findByWord(@Param("word") String word);
```